# mysql sorting messages sent and received

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a table in my database

```
SenderId    ReceiverId  Message         DateAndTime
int(11)     int(11)     varchar(200)    DATETIME
```

I want to sort all messages for a logged user where in conversation style. Messages between logged user say UserA and UserB, UserC should appear like this:

```
UserA   UserB   Sent
UserA   UserB   Sent
UserB   UserA   Received

UserA   UserC   Sent
UserC   UserA   Received
UserA   UserC   Sent

UserD   UserA   Receied
UserA   UserD   Sent
```

I have tried this query but result is not as i expect

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE SenderId like ? or ReceiverId like ? order by senderId, dateAndDate;
```

Comment: so what does the interpolated query look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT SenderId, ReceiverId, Message, DateAndTime, CASE WHEN SenderId=1 THEN ReceiverId Else SenderId END as Optional from messages where SenderId = 1 or ReceiverId=1 order by Optional, DateAndTime desc;
```

Assuming Logged UserID is 1, use place holder instead.

Answer (score 1):

This may work. It doesn't sort conversation by time, but by participants.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(SenderID, ReceiverId), '-', GREATEST(SenderID, ReceiverId)) AS conversation
  , SenderID, ReceiverID, Message, DateAndTime
FROM messages
WHERE SenderID = ? OR ReceiverId =?
ORDER BY conversation, DateAndTime DESC;
```

Comment: this query works too, can you tel me which one is better in terms of performance? yours or query in above answer?

Comment: Their difference is probably too small to ever notice. If I had to guess, mine would be slower because it performs three operations (CONCAT,GREATEST and LEAST) and the other one is one operation (CASE)